# Clocks question - Gain and Loss of time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Raj and Sunil buy the same type of watch from the same shop on the same day and at the same time. After some days, Raj's watch gains as many seconds per hour as Sunil's watch loses per hour. The time of 12.02 hours by Raj's watch equals 11.98 hours by Sunil's watch. How many seconds per hour does Raj's watch gain and Sunil's watch lose?

---

I am not able to understand the question being asked, what do these hours denote ?  All I can take away from this question is that Raj's watch ticks faster than than Sunil's watch.  How to proceed further ?

According to the official solution, actual time duration would be 12 hours, in which Raj's watch gain 0.02 hours , therefore gain is $\frac{0.02}{12}*60*60$ seconds or 6 seconds

I am not able to understand the above solution

Comment: "Raj's watch gains as many seconds per hour as Sunil's watch loses per hour" Do you see how this implies that the correct time is always halfway between the two watches' readings?

Comment: Well, I'd read it as saying that if $R$ measures an interval of $12.02$ hours, $S$ measures the same time interval as $11.98$ hours. So the True Elapsed Time must be $12$ hours, by symmetry.

Comment: Most watches do not show a time of $11.98$; you may have intended $11.58$.  Blame the Babylonians

Comment: I believe both 12.02 and 11.98 are durations in hours not hh.mm time

Comment: The second sentence starts "After some days". Unless we know that they synchronise watches at midnight every day it's anyone's guess how much the watches lose and gain.

Comment: @lulu thank you for the interpretation , what would happen in case instead it was given that one gains twice as many seconds per minute as the other loses , and rest of the question let's say remains the same that is both measure the same interval , R measures it in 12.02 hours and S in 11.98 hours, in that case how would we identify what is correct time that has elapsed ?

Comment: Similar.  Using those numbers, we assume the true time is $X$ with $11.98<X<12.02$.  Then $12.02-X=2(X-11.98)\implies X=11.993$